# How to make my 'angular search list pipe' Case-Insensitive?

Tags: filter, pipe, angular7, case-insensitive

I have a list of jobs and search box. In search box , user enters the job name to search job . I made an angular pipe to search the JOB on the base of typed alphabet by user in search box,means list of job is getting updated having only those item which has typed alphabet by user 
Its working perfectly, but it is case sensitive ,I want to make it case sensitive.
I already made case sensitive  "Contains" based angular pipe.I tried to make searched keyword to on the base of lowercase but did't work.

```
    **TS.file**
    @Pipe({ name: 'filterByName' })
    export class filterNames implements PipeTransform {
      transform(listOfNames: string[], nameToFilter: string, ): string[] {
        var upperLetter=nameToFilter.toUpperCase();
        var smallLetter=nameToFilter.toLowerCase();
        if (!listOfNames) return null;
        if (!nameToFilter) return listOfNames;
        return listOfNames.filter(n =>
   ((n.indexOf(smallLetter) >= 0)||(n.indexOf(upperLetter) >= 0)) 
        );
      }
    }

    **Html file:**
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input [(ngModel)]="filterName" matInput placeholder="Find jobs">
    <mat-form-field

    <mat-nav-list *ngIf ="showlist"  #jobs>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let response of JOBS| filterByName:filterName">
        {{response}} 
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

I expect if user type "A" in search box , list should be updated having list item 'A' and 'a' both. Now in this case , only "A" items are updating.
kindly let me know if anymore input is required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does chaining pipes not help https://angular.io/guide/pipes#chaining-pipes. I.e pipe job to upper or lower case then pipe to your pipe?

Comment: No @AndrewAllen , if i apply this, it will change the case of data which is coming from API, i need to show data  in exact same format in UI as it is coming from API.

Comment: i updated my ts file , but still am doing some mistake , any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by forcing both the name in the `listOfNames` (within the filter) and the `nameToFilter` to uppercase.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByName'
})
export class FilterNamesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(listOfNames: string[], nameToFilter: string=''): string[] {
        var upperLetter = nameToFilter.toUpperCase();
        if (!listOfNames) return null;
        // console.log('listOfNames', listOfNames, 'nameToFilter', nameToFilter, 'upperLetter', upperLetter );
        if (!nameToFilter || nameToFilter === '') return listOfNames;
        return listOfNames.filter(name => 
          name.toUpperCase().startsWith(upperLetter)
        )
  }

}
```

Stackblitz example -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-56307438

Comment: No problem @ArchitGoyal. Please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done @Andrew Allen.